# Error with Preview when logged in through Active Directory

Tags: experience-editor, authentication, azure-ad

I'm experiencing an issue with the Preview functionality when logged in to Sitecore through Azure Active Directory.

Logging in through AD is following this approach:
http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/

Once the Claim is returned from OWIN, a virtual user is created with the Role information from the claim and then logged into Sitecore.

Logging into Sitecore works just fine and I'm able to open up and use Experience Editor as normal. Whenever I try to launch Preview (either from the Publish tab or ribbon bar in Experience Editor), the below exception is thrown.

After the below error has occurred, the user must also re-log in to Sitecore again. If they try to close the preview tab and continue in Sitecore, the same error occurs.

One thing I have noticed when debugging through this is that when viewing Preview the `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs.Context.User.Identity.Name` changes from ***sitecore/userEmail*** to ***default/anonymous***. Not sure if the change in user identity for Preview would be causing an automatic log out of the user when logged in through AD.

Has anybody run into something similar or know where to start looking?

> 7976 13:35:20 ERROR Application error. Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException Message: membership user Source:
>   Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.HasAccessForLogin(Ticket
>   ticket)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.Relogin(String
>   ticketId, Boolean redirect)    at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.IsLoggedIn(Boolean returnAfterLogin)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.EnsureLoggedInForPreview.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that there is a configuration setting that can be enabled which runs the preview mode with the currently logged in user (an authenticated user) instead of the `default/anonymous` user.

It's called `Preview.AsAnonymous`, and setting this setting to `false` will allow users to preview as the currently authenticated user instead.

Source: [USING AN AUTHENTICATED PREVIEW IN SITECORE](https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/using-an-authenticated-preview-in-sitecore/)